# Relationship between Alexander, Chandragupta Maurya and Seleucus.

Tags: india, roman-empire, ancient-india

How Alexander, [Chandragupta Maurya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandragupta_Maurya) and Seleucus were related to each other?

Comment: "they were not related" ... of course this isn't really what you are asking, however, what research have you done, and what are you really asking? The answer can be as short as a few words, or as lengthy as a thesis or novel. As it is this is an extremely broad question.

Comment: @CGCampbell Seleucus was commander in Alexander's army and after the death of Alexander he tried to invade India but was defeated by Chandragupta Maurya. + Other down voters please mention your reason behind it. :)

Comment: The down-votes were, probably, due to "This question does not show any research effort" and the close votes are self-explanatory, in that the question is much too broad. As I said a book could be (and probably has been somewhere) written about that period and those individuals. As far as my "not related" comment, I meant that in the American/English meaning of the word: they were neither parents or siblings, nor were they married to one another, and thus "were not related"

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great) Alexander invaded India in 326 BC in the battle of Hydaspes. Later he returned back.

After the death of Alexander, Seleucus, who was commander in Alexander's army attacked India but he was [defeated by the king Chandragupta Maurya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seleucid%E2%80%93Mauryan_war)
So Seleucus and Chandragupta Maurya signed a treaty as well and Seleucus appointed an ambassador who was no one but the Megasthenes.

After the Seleucid-Mauryan war Chandragupta Maurya married to [Durdhara](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durdhara) who was daughter of Seleucus. 
So,
Chandragupta and Seleucus were relatives like this, and as Seleucus was commander of Alexander's army so Chandragupta was indirectly related to him also.